# Import Existing Android Project into Eclipse - Project Build Target

Tags: android, eclipse

**Eclipse/Android Problem**

Does anyone have a straightforward solution to this problem encountered whilst importing an existing Android project into Eclipse.

The intention of using an existing Android project was specifically to utilise the Eclipse ADT Export Wizard to produce a signed .apk that should work on Android devices from version 1 upwards.

The existent Android project has already been tested on my device (Android version 2.3.3) and functions correctly.

**Tools used:**

Android SDK/Eclipse IDE bundle, plus Java JDK.

All tools function correctly.

**Import Existing Android Project Process:**

Open Eclipse > File > New > Project > Android Project From Existing Code > Next > Browse to select project from root directory > Select project > Finish).

This process worked & the existing Android project was imported & displayed the left hand side of the Eclipse console under the Project Explorer View.

I then signed the project using the Eclipse ADT Export Wizard before exporting the final .apk.

**Summary:**

All software appeared to work correctly.

Signing process appeared to have worked correctly.

Export of .apk appeared to have worked correctly.

However, the resultant .apk would not install on my mobile device (Android Build 2.3.3).

**The Problem:**

I noticed that when I imported my existent Android project into Eclipse that a folder had been created called 'Android 4.4'. This was visible in the left hand side of the Eclipse console in the Project Explorer View when the Project Folder was expanded.

I suspect this is the cause of the problem i.e. the exported/signed .apk may only be compatible with Android devices using version 4.4 and upward & therefore may be the reason it may not install on my device.

Is there a simple way to re-assign this version '4.4' folder with an earlier version i.e. '1'.

(I've tried right clicking the Project Folder > Properties > Android to see if it's possible to change the target version here, but there only seems to be one fixed value of '4.4' re: Project Build Target).

Anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: better approach post the androidmanifest as we want to see if the mind and max sdk targets are set right....

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I've just posted an update to the question detailing minSDKValue and targetSDKValue.

Comment: RE: AndroidManifest.xml:
minSDKVersion = "10"
targetSDKVersion ="19"

RE: project.properties:
target=android-19

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to look at & reply to this question. The procedure outlined above worked after a reinstall of the Eclipse IDE / Android SDK bundle (March 2014).